# Sequestered in or to

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions, phrase-usage

In the case of the past tense verb *sequestered*, which preposition is correct:  *in* or *to*?

The twelve were sequestered to the jury room.

The twelve were sequestered in the jury room.

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine.

"*Sequester to*" emphasizes direction.

"*Sequester in*" emphasizes result.